# Run Cron Job on PHP Script, on localhost in Windows

Tags: php, windows, cron, localhost, wamp

I have a php script and want to run it on an schedule. I am using local web server on windows (WAMP server) and need a way to run `my_script.php` **every 10 min**.

How to run a cron job on a PHP script, on localhost in windows?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

recently I had sort of problems to run a cron job on a php script on localhost (WAMP server) in windows 7, when I was on a test to chronically fetch some links from www out there.

By the way I am sharing this for anyone that is on the same thing.

You will need a **shellscript** to run chronically, using **Windows Task Scheduler**. Also you will need a batch script (**script.bat**) to call the **php.exe** and run your **php script** (here called as `my_process.php`)

**shellscript.vbs**

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\path\to\script\script.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

**script.bat**

```
"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe" -f "C:\wamp\www\website\my_process.php"
```

Now, we are ready to set the **Windows Task Scheduler** to run **shellscript.vbs** at the required time interval:

1. Open **Task Scheduler** from windows **Start** menu
2. Go to **Action** menu and hit **Create Task...**
3. in *General* tab, fill the **Name** and **Description** fields as you want
4. in *Triggers* tab, hit **New** button.
5. from *Begin the Task* dropdown, select **On a schedule** and choose **Daily**
6. from *Advanced settings* section, select **Repeat task every** as you want and set *for a duration* on **Indefinitely**.
7. on *Actions* tab, from *Action* dropdown, select **Start a program**.
8. on the *Program\script* box, enter path to shellscript.vbs like **C:\path\to\shellscript.vbs**.
9. leave *Add argumentts (optional)* section empty.
10. in *Start in (optional)* box, enter parent directory of shellscript.vbs like `C:\path\to\`.
11. Hit upvote on this tutorial :) Have fun.

Comment: I followed your tutorial, however I had errors in my log. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618945/why-windows-7-task-scheduler-task-fails-with-error-2147942667) helped me solve the error.

Comment: I have a problem, with this procedure, the task is beinge executed, however my php script it's not running, I got the "Open with" dialogue. If I see the properties of my task, it states: `ActionName C:\Windows\system32\OpenWith.exe ` even if I set it to the `vbs` file as you suggested. What am I doing wrong? THANKS

Comment: Can you pls tell me do i have to create .Bat file or .vbs file?

Comment: Please include that creating a .vbs and .bat file is as simple as creating a .php file from a text document... simplest part got me baffled xD

Comment: I got it to work after selecting "Run with Highest Privileges" in the General tab, just a tip for anyone crossing this!

Answer (score 1):

To setup a Windows machine to run cron.php at a specific time follow the specific instructions below. This can be useful if you are not familiar with Linux/Unix, or if your web host does not offer the ability to run cron jobs; you can run them remotely from your own computer.

Note: These instructions were written for Windows XP but should be similar in other versions of Windows.

https://www.drupal.org/node/31506

Answer (score 1):

If you use answer from **Trix** and get same problem as **Metafaniel**:

> I have a problem, with this procedure, the task is beinge executed,
>   however my php script it's not running, I got the "Open with"
>   dialogue. If I see the properties of my task, it states: ActionName
>   C:\Windows\system32\OpenWith.exe even if I set it to the vbs file as
>   you suggested. What am I doing wrong?

you should use this:

8. Instead "enter path to shellscript.vbs like C:\path\to\shellscript.vbs." use "C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe"
9. Instead "leave Add argumentts (optional) section empty" use (with quotes):
   "C:\path\to\shellscript.vbs"

Answer (score 1):

After many failed attempts at using Windows Task Scheduler this is the method that worked for me on my Windows 10 Professional machine. I just skipped adding a .vbs and .bat file and posted the PATH to the script file directly.

Under "**Actions > Settings**" Where it gives the option to browse for a "**Program/Script**" that's where I put the **full PATH AND Filename to the script** I wanted to run WITHOUT quotes.

```
C:\Server\Scripts\script.py
```

Then in the same area under "**Actions > Settings**" right below the text box where you just entered your "Program/Script", it has the area that says "**Start in (optional)**". That's where I put the **PATH to the program that runs the script** (ie: python.exe in this instance). But I did not specify "python.exe" directly I used the **PATH ONLY** without quotes like shown below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64
```

If you installed Python directly without Visual Studio it will be under a different path probably something like "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37" or something similar if I remember correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late but just for someone who don't want it to be lengthy and don't want to waste time in testing (as the aim is to host it to server), can do one thing by adding http content refresh in the html meta tag of that php file and add the required timer to it and run it in the browser.
NOTE: You have to make the system remain open untill you don't get the required output.
Again I am saying this is not the perfect and proper way but ya can save someone's configuration setting time.