# How to go about updating a MySQL Table from a CSV file every [time interval]?

Tags: mysql, csv, transfer, schedule

Firstly, I understand that attempting to do this from MySQL itself is not allowed:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

When I try to use `LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/data.csv' ...` , I get the "LOAD DATA IS NOT ALLOWED IN STORED PROCEDURES".

I am a beginner with moving data around MySQL and I realize this may not be a task it was designed to handle.  Therefore, what approach should I use to grab data from a CSV file and append it to a table at a regular time interval? (I have researched a little bit about CRON, but that is for UNIX systems only and we are using a Windows based OS.)

Comment: i had a similar requirement. The way I solved it, Used java code to run a script that runs Load DataIn file command

Comment: Would this be through developing a java application that would connect to the MySQL database and execute the command that way?

Comment: You can run cron job on windows also. Please look in to this link:
http://www.waytocode.com/2012/setup-cron-job-on-windows-server/ 
I found another link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: Thank you @sayani ; if you post this as an answer, I will select it as the answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run CRON job on windows also. I have found a couple of links after searching. Please look in to these links:

```
waytocode.com/2012/setup-cron-job-on-windows-server

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows
```