# Run php script using .bat every X time

Tags: php, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a program which is sending and receiving text messages and auto process the massage.

For other reason's I don't need to use JavaScript or HTML to refresh the page so I can send the message, so for the program to send back the message I need to use .bat or any window automated system

My question is how can I run the send.php file every 10 sec using .bat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Cron Job on PHP Script, on localhost in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows)

Comment: I never understand why its quicker to register and post a question on here than it is to search Google/StackOverflow and click the first result ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\PHP"
:loop
call php  ./folder/folder2/sent.php
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 >NUL
goto :loop
```

Comment: Cool you mean I should put the script where the send file is?

Comment: @FetchLazy - I think so.The answer has been edited.Now you need just to try it.

Comment: Is giving error, php is not recognised as internal or external command

Comment: @FetchLazy - so `php.exe` is not in the `%path%` . check [this](http://php.net/manual/bg/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath)

Comment: In 'Environment Variables' PATHEXT I have added C:\PHP and restart the PC still the same problem I even change C:\PHP to .PHP only but no lucky

Comment: @FetchLazy  - `PATHEXT` is another kind of beer.You need to put it in `PATH` variable.

Comment: Can I see example if possible maybe I miss the totorial

Comment: @FetchLazy  - I've edited the script and it adds `C:\PHP` to the path.

Comment: @FetchLazy - may be this will be more clear -> https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/

Comment: Stil having the problem, my wamp server was installed in folder cloud maybe it has something to do with this?. I tried to change php to notepad.exe I was able to open the file