# Automatically delete uploaded image after some time PHP

Tags: php, file, upload, wamp

I created an application to upload image using PHP, Javascript and WAMP server. I need to deleted automatically the uploaded image after some time, say X mins. How this can be achieved?

Thanks...

Comment: You can set cronjob method on server which will delete all images inside any folder..

Comment: You could have a cron job running every N minutes that would delete all files older than X mins (using find & rm for example). There is no real point using PHP to do that here

Comment: he is running WAMP, which is a Windows thing. So he probably doesn't know what you mean.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Exactly.  here is what a cron is http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml  - once you know what this is, you should be able to understand what you need to do next

Comment: Look up `Windows Task Scheduler`. Create a `PHP CLI Script` to do what you want and schedule it however often you want to, or maybe you can do it with a simple `.bat` or `.cmd` file instead

Comment: @DharaParmar WAMP.... The W stands for `Windows` therefor no cron use Task Scheduler instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Solution:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * FileName: ajax-processor.php
         */
        $uploadDir  = __DIR__ . "/uploads";   // HERE: YOU SPECIFY THE PATH TO THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY
        $action     = isset($_POST['action'])   ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['action']))      : null;
        $imageAge   = isset($_POST['imageAge']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['imageAge']))    : 24;

        // IF AJAX TELLS US TO DELETE ALL IMAGES & GIVES US THE MAXIMUM AGE OF THE IMAGES TO BE DELETED
        // WE NOW FIRE THE COMMANDS BELOW.
        // NOTE THAT USING THE imageAge WE CAN DECIDE THE FILES THAT WOULD BE DELETED SINCE WE DON'T WANT ALL DELETED
        // THE DEFAULT HERE WOULD BE 24 HOURS...
        if($action=="delete" && $imageAge>0){
            $deletionReport = removeImagesInFolder($uploadDir, $imageAge);
            return json_encode($deletionReport);
        }

        function getImagesInFolder($dir_full_path){
            $returnable     = array();
            $files_in_dir   = scandir($dir_full_path);
            $reg_fx         = '/(\.png$)|(\.jpg$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.tiff$)/';
            foreach($files_in_dir as $key=>$val){
                $temp_file_or_dir = $dir_full_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $val;
                if(is_file($temp_file_or_dir) && preg_match($reg_fx,  $val) ){
                    $regx_dot_wateva            = '/\.{2,4}$/';
                    $regx_dot                   = '/\./';
                    $regx_array                 = array($regx_dot_wateva, $regx_dot);
                    $replace_array              = array("", "_");
                    $return_val                 = preg_replace($regx_array, $replace_array, $val);
                    $returnable[$return_val]    = $temp_file_or_dir ;
                }else if(is_dir($temp_file_or_dir) && !preg_match('/^\..*/', $val) ){
                    getImagesInFolder($temp_file_or_dir);
                }
            }
            return $returnable;
        }

        function removeImagesInFolder($imgFolder, $imageAgeInHours=24){
            //CHANGE FILE-PERMISSION ON THE IMAGE DIRECTORY SO YOU COULD WORK WITH IT.
            chmod($imgFolder, 0755);

            $arrImages          = getImagesInFolder($imgFolder);
            $statusReport       = array();
            foreach($arrImages as $imgKey=>$imageFile){
                $imageAgeInSecs     = $imageAgeInHours*60*60;
                if (file_exists($imageFile)) {
                    $now            = time();
                    $fileModTime    = filemtime($imageFile);
                    $fileAge        = ($now - $fileModTime);

                    if($fileAge >= $imageAgeInSecs){
                        /* BE CAREFUL: THE GIVEN FILE WOULD ACTUALLY BE DELETE!!! */
                        //HERE IS A LITTLE ADDITION FOR PERMISSION ISSUES
                        //NOTE THAT I DID NOT TEST THIS SINCE I AM NOT ON A WINDOWS SYSTEM & I DON'T USE WAMP... BUT I THINK THIS MAY DO THE TRICK
                        //CHANGE FILE-PERMISSION ON THE IMAGE FILE SO YOU COULD DELETE IT.
                        chmod($imageFile, 0755); //GIVES THE ADMINISTRATOR RIGHT TO DO EVERYTHING WITH THE FILE; BUT ALLOWS ONLY READING/EXECUTION FOR OTHER USERS.
                        if( unlink($imageFile) ) {

                            $statusReport[] = "Deleted " . $imageFile . ". This File is about " . ($fileAge / (24 * 60 * 60)) . " Day(s) Old.";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $statusReport;
        }

    ?>
```

Here is the Javascript  that glues the whole Process...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var iInterval   = setInterval(deleteImagesViaAjax, 1000*60+60);    //DELETE IMAGES EVERY HOUR

                function deleteImagesViaAjax(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/framework/ajax-processor.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({
                            action      : 'delete',
                            imageAge    : 24            //MAXIMUM AGE OF THE IMAGE TO DELETE IN HOURS - THIS MEANS ALL IMAGES UPLOADED ABOUT 24 HOURS AGO 
                        }),

                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },

                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                        },

                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Warning: unlink(.): Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\ImageUploadApp\ajax-processor.php

Comment: Am getting a warning like this. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Cron Job is the right tool you need. Cron in windows is a little hard to achieve by using php. if youa are using a framework its easy to do it. But the following links will help you achieve your goal.

[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

[Run Cron Job on PHP Script, on localhost in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows)

Comment: UNIX = `CRON` - Windows = `Task Scheduler` its just as good, maybe better