# Local hosted page

Tags: localhost

Good day,

I am not a programmer by profession and I didn't study formally, I am currently self learning. So my Question might seem stupid or don't understand the answers. Please forgive me.

Okay the question:

My example will be for an internal team lunch roster it will be local page where users can set there lunch times and will not be changed but will reset at the end of the day.

All changes can be viewed by openning up the page.

I would like to know should it be a java and html or what language should I create such page on.

Kind regards

Comment: Download XAMPP software with apache+PHP+MySQL and start building website on PHP.

Comment: java is not a web language however it can be used for web. You may want to use mysql and PHP for your project.

Comment: Any web programming language can be used for this.  PHP, Java, C#, Ruby, JavaScript, Python, etc., etc.  Basically pick a language and start with some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement, it's better to create a local website @ intranet developed using PHP with automated script to reset the data for lunch at the end of the week. You can use Xampp, Wamp or any web server software of your choices.

[Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

ps: you can use this guide to create an automated script
[Run Cron Job on PHP Script, on localhost in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035090/run-cron-job-on-php-script-on-localhost-in-windows)