# Task Scheduler-Windows server 2012 - Last Run of the task is terminated by user

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

On my production server (Windows server 2012) i have scheduled various tasks. I have enabled Task Scheduler history but its of no use. LastRunResult of each of my tasks shows "Last run of the task was terminated by user" which means authenticated program had terminated this task. but there is no such program configured which may stop all these tasks.Because of this tasks are not getting completed
 1.How can i track which program/task caused this ?
There is a huge time difference between these scheduled tasks so what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on all servers after scheduling a task to run at a specific time and subsequently changing the time zone from EDT to UTC prior to the scheduled start time.  Perhaps you did something similar?

I'm not sure why changing the time zone would have affected the task I'd scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it not always a different application which stops the task, it can be time-limit or anything else, that relates to the same user which started the task. For example, if you set this:
[image: Task settings]

And it reaches the time limit:
[image: Task history]

You will see `The last run of the task was terminated by the user. (0x41306)` as Last Run Result. (don't ask me why, makes no sense):
[image: Task list]

But these will be logged in the history, however interestingly AFTER the task is finished...

If there's nothing in the history, try to log. If it's a power shell script you can use the `<command arguments> *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath C:\Logs\Scheduled-run\test-run\logs-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss).log` (directories must exists and must be writeable by the user which triggered the scheduled task! or exits with 0x1) to have the command output somewhere for every run.

You can also log things that you are doing by adding logs inside your application/script that you schedule. This is good to see how long it runs and what's going on meanwhile. Does it interfere with another task? Does it interfere with periodic server restart?

You can also check the windows system events if there is something there which can indicate something.

You can also try a wrapper like this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/what-killed-my-process/ba-p/375329

Or if you have an error value then this: [Why does my Task Scheduler task fail with error 2147942667?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618945/why-does-my-task-scheduler-task-fail-with-error-2147942667)