# How to automate a script in R using taskscheduleR?

Tags: r, automation, windows-task-scheduler, r-taskscheduler

I am currently looking at this [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/readme/README.html) to automate a script on my machine using R and taskscheduleR. I am confused within this documentation of the following:

**In the example within the documentation, what is "extdata", is this supposed to be the file path of my R script and is "helloworld.R" the actual R script?**

```
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "helloworld.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
```

**My current take at this is below:** Where C:/Users/santi/Documents/R Scripts is my file path and Wayerhaeuser_Automation_script.R is my actual R script

```
myscript <- system.file("C:/Users/santi/Documents/R Scripts", "Wayerhaeuser_Automation_script.R", package = "taskscheduleR")

taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 62, "%H:%M"))
```

I was a bit confused on the documentation of it.

Attempt after trying proposed solution:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my Task Scheduler task fail with error 2147942667?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618945/why-does-my-task-scheduler-task-fail-with-error-2147942667)

Comment: Note - the error above (2147842667) is what Windows Event Logs record for a Task that has a run result of (0x1).

Answer (score 0):

Change `myscript` to:

```
myscript <- paste0("C:/Users/santi/Documents/R Scripts/","Wayerhaeuser_Automation_script.R")
```

and it should work just fine. The `rscript` argument is just a string path to the file to run. Sometimes paths are interpreted improperly if there are spaces, so if it doesn't work, also try changing the folder name to R_Scripts

Comment: Thanks I did this and the script did not run. Within my task schedulder Last Run Result column I geta message of `0x1` I am unsure what that means. I will update the question with a screenshot

Comment: This may help you out, it can be something to do with permissions on Windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370547/windows-scheduled-task-succeeds-but-returns-result-0x1

Comment: Thanks, I have followed the directions and I am now getting a `directory name is invalid` error. If I am understanding correctly do I need to explicity type Program/Script in the Start in (optional): area?

Comment: @Jaskeil "*directory name is invalid*" means Windows can't find or access the directory you have specified. My first guess is you used forward slashes when Windows file directory uses back slashes instead (e.g. it should be "C:\Users\santi\...", not "C:/Users/santi/...". Windows has no concept of something called "C:/".